# Set the length of an experiment in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I am very new to ANYLOGIC. I have used the tutorial to build the windfarm model and have run the simulation. Just looking to set the length of the simulation to 2 weeks and then export the data on number of turbines offline over the period.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options

the first one is to change it in your simulation experiment:
[image: stop time]

this number corresponds to what your model time units are that you can change in your initial project properties

[image: project]

another option, is to do it by code, you can go to Main on startup and use this code:

```
getEngine().setStopTime(2, WEEK);
```